# PHP - How to remove particular tag from HTML-Code

Tags: php, regex

How to remove every

```
<script></script>
```

Element in a HTML file? I tried the following regex:

```
 preg_replace("/<script.*\/script>/", "", $html);
```

But it only works when the code is in just 1 single line. When a \n (newline) occurs it doesn't want to work. Any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the s modifier to your regex. The s modifier include newlines in "." Wildcard.

But you can think about some html sanitizers like htmlpurifier or simply use strip_tags if you want to remove some malicious code from html input

Comment: Great, works, Thanks. Only problem was that it got too greedy. Solved it by with the u-modifier.

Comment: instead of u, you can add an ? to * or + and you get an non greedy version

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
$HTML = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"), '', $HTML);

preg_replace("/<script.*\/script>/", "", $html);
```

Remove all breakline before. Problem solved.

Comment: Why not simply add s modifier to the regex!?

Comment: @Philipp Because I didn't know about Regex !